# Object pivot point in Delphi

Tags: delphi, animation, firemonkey

I have an object as shown in the screenshot which I generate using the PATH component.
I use the "ROTATION" method to rotate the object. However, the system takes the center of the object for rotation. I would like it to take the point (0,0) which is the upper left corner, so that the animation forms a circle. How can this be achieved programmatically ?

[image]

Comment: Set RotationCenter to 0,0 instead of the default 0.5,0.5. Or show some code of what you are actually doing so others don't need to guess.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Problem solved. It was a stupid question. Sorry, I didn't notice that property